# vue-chartjs: You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file

Tags: vue-chartjs

I added vue-chartjs as per instruction (https://vue-chartjs.org/ja/guide/).
% yarn add vue-chartjs chart.js@2.9.4

Then ran % yarn dev.

Now I see this error on console.

```
Loading...
ERROR in ./node_modules/vue-chartjs/dist/index.js 198:37
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (198:37)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|             const ref = shallowRef(null);
|             const reforwardRef = (chartRef)=>{
>                 ref.value = chartRef?.chart;
|             };
|             expose({
```

Reproduction

I can give an access to the repository if needed.

chart.js version

2.9.4

vue-chartjs version

^5.2.0

Possible solution

I did try installing style-loader css-loader, but it caused another error.

```
in ./.nuxt/components/nuxt-error.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=74e3df5b&lang=css& (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--3-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--3-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./.nuxt/components/nuxt-error.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=74e3df5b&lang=css&)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):
TypeError: this.getOptions is not a function
    at Object.loader (/Users/tenna/Desktop/Henshin-Bike-Tomo/manageWeb/hajimenavi_manage/node_modules/css-loader/dist/index.js:22:27)
```

% yarn add vue-chartjs chart.js@2.9.4
% yarn dev

Answer (score 0):

Using chart.js version 3.9.1 fixed the problem for me.

```
npm i --save chart.js@3.9.1
```